# Github API is responding with a 403 when using Request's request function

Tags: node.js, request, github-api

I am trying to make a request to github's API. Here is my request:

```
var url = 'https://api.github.com/' + requestUrl + '/' + repo + '/';

request(url, function(err, res, body) {
    if (!err && res.statusCode == 200) {

        var link = "https://github.com/" + repo;
        opener(link);
        process.exit();

    } else {
        console.log(res.body);
        console.log(err);
        console.log('This ' + person + ' does not exist');
        process.exit();
    }

});
```

This is what I get for my response:

```
Request forbidden by administrative rules. Please make sure your request has a User-Agent header (http://developer.github.com/v3/#user-agent-required). Check https://developer.github.com for other possible causes.
```

I have used the exact same code in the past, and it has worked. No errors are being thrown by request. Now I am confused with why I am getting a 403 (Forbidden)? Any solutions?

Comment: Add a user agent header or just use the module(s) on npm for the github API.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

As explained in the [URL given in the response](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/using-the-rest-api/troubleshooting-the-rest-api?apiVersion=2022-11-28#user-agent-required), requests to GitHub's API now require a `User-Agent` header:

> All API requests MUST include a valid `User-Agent` header. Requests with no `User-Agent` header will be rejected. We request that you use your GitHub username, or the name of your application, for the `User-Agent` header value. This allows us to contact you if there are problems.

The `request` documentation [shows specifically](https://github.com/request/request#custom-http-headers) how to add a `User-Agent` header to your request:

```
var request = require('request');

var options = {
  url: 'https://api.github.com/repos/request/request',
  headers: {
    'User-Agent': 'request'
  }
};

function callback(error, response, body) {
  if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
    var info = JSON.parse(body);
    console.log(info.stargazers_count + " Stars");
    console.log(info.forks_count + " Forks");
  }
}

request(options, callback);
```

Answer (score 7):

> From C# and using `HttpClient` you can do this (tested on latest .Net Core 2.1):

```
using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
{
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add( new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.UserAgent.TryParseAdd("request");//Set the User Agent to "request"

    using (HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync(endPoint).Result)
    {
        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
        responseBody = await response.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync();
    }
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If Github API is responding with status Code : 403, It simply mean
that your API fetching limit has been exceeded please wait for 1 min and again fetch then you will get your data,

Answer (score 0):

**ANGULAR**

I had the same issue where I got 403 rate limit exceeded. I tried setting up the `Authorization` header using `new HttpHeaders` from angular/common but the header still failed.
The code that failed is:

```
getUser(username: string): Observable<any> {
    this.headers.set('Authorization', `token ${this.ACCESS_TOKEN}`);
    const endpoint = `https://api.github.com/users/${username}`;
    return this.http.get(endpoint, {
      headers: this.headers
    }).pipe(response => {
      return response
    });
  }
```

The code that worked:

```
getUser(username: string): Observable<any> {
    const endpoint = `https://api.github.com/users/${username}`;
    return this.http.get(endpoint, {
      headers: {
        Authorization: `token ${this.ACCESS_TOKEN}`,
      }
    }).pipe(response => {
      return response
    });
  }
```

In this case, I directly set the header in the request headers segment.

Answer (score 0):

This answers the question and as a bonus shows you how to check if there is a new release

You need to add a `User-agent` to the `Request`

`request.UserAgent = "YourRepoName";`

```
    internal class Tag
    {
        [JsonProperty("tag_name")]
        public string TagName { get; set; }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Use the Github API to Check for Updates
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static Task<string> CheckUpTodate()
    {
        try
        {
            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://api.github.com/repos/HypsyNZ/BinanceTrader.NET/releases");
            request.UserAgent = new Random(new Random().Next()).ToString();

            var response = request.GetResponse();
            if (response != null)
            {
                StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());

                string readerOutput = reader.ReadToEnd();

                List<Tag>? deserializedString = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Tag>>(readerOutput);
                if (deserializedString != null)
                {
                    if (deserializedString.Count > 0)
                    {
                        Tag tagOnFirstRelease = deserializedString.FirstOrDefault();
                        if ("v" + ObservableObject.Version == tagOnFirstRelease.TagName)
                        {
                            return Task.FromResult("Up To Date");
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            return Task.FromResult("Update Available: " + tagOnFirstRelease.TagName);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // Error
        }

        return Task.FromResult("Unknown");
    }
```