# getting 403 error while sending file to githib via REST using nodejs

Tags: node.js, git

I want to send multiple files to Github repository via nodejs. Tried several approaches and end up using node-rest-client module. Tried below code send a sample file to repository called 'metadata'. But after post I am getting error message "Request forbidden by administrative rules. Please make sure your request has a User-Agent header"...please let me know if anyone faced this error before and get rid of it.

```
convertval = "somedata";
var dataObj = {
    "message": "my commit message",
    "committer": {
      "name": "Scott Chacon",
      "email": "ravindra.devagiri@gmail.com"
    },
    "content": "bXkgbmV3IGZpbGUgY29udGVudHM="
  }
debugger;
var Client = require('node-rest-client').Client;
var client = new Client()            
var args = {
    data: dataObj,
    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
};
client.post("https://api.github.com/repos/metadata/contents", args, function (data, response) {
    console.log("file send: True : " + data);
});
```

Comment: "Please make sure your request has a User-Agent header" - can you try adding a User-Agent header to your request? I'm surprised node-rest-client doesn't have a default one though.

Comment: Your URL is broken: there's no github.com/metadata/contents. Try something that does exist, e.g. https://api.github.com/repos/octokit/rest.js or https://api.github.com/repos/octokit/rest.js/contents

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to define 'User-Agent' with value 'request' in your request header. Refer to this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39907742/github-api-is-responding-with-a-403-when-using-requests-request-function).

Second, endpoint you are trying to call might require authentication. Generate a personal token from [here](https://github.com/settings/tokens), add that token in your request header, 'Authorization': 'token '.

If you're using Git extensively in your code, I suggest you to use this - [Nodegit](https://www.nodegit.org/).

Edit:
I don't think sending multiple files in a single request is possible in 'Contents' endpoints group ([link](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/contents/)).

You can checkout Git Data API (as discussed [here](https://github.com/isaacs/github/issues/199)).

Comment: tried by adding user-agent and  Authorization token, but I am getting 404 error

Comment: Please read link after edit, https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/contents/

404 means that either API endpoint you are trying does not exist, your API path parameters are wrong or repository does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [REST API](https://developer.github.com/v3/#user-agent-required):

> All API requests MUST include a valid User-Agent header. Requests with
>   no User-Agent header will be rejected.

Comment: Added User-Agent and headers properly
`headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Authorization': '8566e4717dbcfebf05c857804a931732a9541283' ,
            'User-Agent': 'request'`
but still getting 404 error - message: "Not Found"

Comment: @ravindradevagiri, as advised in other comments, please check that you have the correct url or that the repo is enabled and available.